# spring poller against jdbc backed queue channel - Clustered mode

Tags: spring-integration

Will a message get processed twice(meaning in more than 1 cluster node) in the below scenario?
1. A jdbc message store backed queue channel containing pending messages
2. Poller configured on the message consumer side to process messages

Does the jdbc message store lock messages once picked for processing to avoid the message being re-processed in another cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

discussed here http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?112446-spring-poller-against-jdbc-backed-queue-channel-Clustered-mode&highlight=poller